# Setup Swagger Configuration in Micronaut

Tags: swagger, micronaut

I have an existing micronaut application, not written by me, which already has a swagger configuration, but is not working and I am trying to understand why.

First looking at the documentation:
[OpenAPI/Swagger Support](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-openapi/1.4.5/guide/index.html)

it says that the yaml file will be generated to the META-INF/swagger ... however I can't find that folder in the project.

(The swagger dependencies are defined)

In the project (resources) yaml file there is a configuration:

```
application:
  api:
    swagger:
      path: /openapi-doc/swagger
      version: 3.22.2
      urls:
        - name: student
          url: /openapi-doc/swagger/student-api.yml
        - name: course
          url: /openapi-doc/swagger/course-api.yml
```

That means there should be in the project the folder **/openapi-doc/** ? or it will be generated automatically? because I couldn't find a folder under that name

Or I need to create the folder in the root project?

So is not going to be generated under the folder **META-INF/swagger**

Comment: When you build the app is anything generated under `build/classes/java/main/META-INF/swagger`?

Comment: The path I mentioned in the previous comment would relate to Gradle.  If you are using Maven, same question would apply to `target/classes/META-INF/swagger`.

Comment: It is difficult to say what is wrong in your project but a good starting point may be to create an app at https://micronaut.io/launch/ with the `openapi` feature and see if the docs are properly generated for you in that project.

Comment: ah yes, i found it in maven, swagger.yml. However it only has one line with "openapi: 3.0.1  Yes is a good idea your suggestion, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That means there should be in the project the folder /openapi-doc/ ?

No.  I don't think that references a project folder.  I think that references a URI.

> or it will be generated automatically?

The docs should be generated automatically if the build is properly configured.

> Or I need to create the folder in the root project?

I don't think you will need to create anything in the root of the project.